# Contact Form 7 Javascript loading late

Tags: javascript, contact-form-7

I have a piece of code in a external Javascript file that adds a tooltip to all Contact Form 7 forms with an acceptance checkbox.

it works if within a timeout;

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    setTimeout(() => {
        $('.wpcf7-submit[disabled]').after('<div class="wpcf7-tooltip">Check the consent field to continue</div>');
}, "2000");

});
```

but doesn't work without.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.wpcf7-submit[disabled]').after('<div class="wpcf7-tooltip">Check the consent field to continue</div>');
});
```

This Javascript file is loaded after Contact Form 7 Javascript dependencies (except CF7 Recaptcha).

Any idea why and how I can resolve this without timeout? - not that it's a problem to wrap it in this function but it's inelegant and I'd like to know how to track and resolve this.

Comment: it seems like the script is running before the Contact Form 7 elements are fully initialized or rendered.

Have you tried $( document ).ready(function() {
    /* function here */ 
}); ?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer, the function above was wrapped  like that, I'll edit it.

Answer (score 1):

If you control the code that creates the form, you can make it fire some event to notify you that it's been created.

Otherwise, you could set a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) which is better than polling the DOM for that node, which would have been better than the hardcoded wait you currently have.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  const body = document.body;

  function tryToAppendToSubmit() {
    const submitButton = $('.wpcf7-submit[disabled]');
    if (!submitButton.length) {
      return false;
    }
    submitButton.after(
      '<div class="wpcf7-tooltip">Check the consent field to continue</div>'
    );
    return true;
  }

  document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
    $(body).append(`<input class="wpcf7-submit" disabled />`)
  })

  // Check if it exists. It won't exist in this example
  // but it could in your example?
  if (tryToAppendToSubmit()) {
    return;
  }

  const callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
    for (const mutation of mutationsList) {
      // Checking for additions, you may need to check 
      // modifications.
      if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
        for (const addedNode of mutation.addedNodes) {
          if (addedNode.nodeType === 1 && addedNode.classList.contains('wpcf7-submit')) {
            console.log('.wpcf7-submit element added!');
            tryToAppendToSubmit()
            // Stop observing once the change is detected 
            observer.disconnect();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };

  const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
  observer.observe(body, {
    attributes: true,
    subtree: true,
    childList: true
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Button below will add a disabled <code>.wpcf7-submit</code> input field.
<p>The observer will detect it and create the <code>.wpcf7-tooltip</code>. Note that it will only do it the first time you click since this example disconnects the <i>MutationObserver</i>
<hr />
<button id="btn">Add input field</button>
```

Comment: Wow. That takes me into realms way above my pay grade but 'every day's a learning day' so thank you, I shall do some research.